# I want to add another tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4523/99) question, however I felt that it needed another tag describing the *interaction between courses*, and also a group with *academic problems*, but after reading the list of existing tags I couldn't find any that fit. May be I skip them, may be those situations don't need tags, I want to know first before trying to make them appear.

Comment: There is  [tag:struggling-students] that might fit for the one. For interaction between courses, I do not know [tag:prerequisites] might fit sometimes but not always. It might also make sense to have a tag for interaction with other teachers more generally. I am not sure what would be an idomatic way of making a tag of this though.

Comment: I was thinking using literally _interaction-between-courses_, or maybe _courses-interface_, or _course-vs-course_. It's so bad there isn't an idiom for this idea (perhaps in another language hehe)

Comment: The name interaction-between-courses is too long (there is a rather low limit on the length of tags, namely 25), but interactions-of-courses would work as would interacting-courses Generally speaking, the idea of such a tag seems reasonable to me. Perhaps some native speaker could weigh in on the precise wording.

Answer (score 3):

In response to the question and comments, here are some ideas:

One possibility is **course-connections**, and I would suggest that the description indicate clearly how this tag differs from **prerequisites**. We could potentially *only* use the former, and allow it to subsume the latter; however, I think the type of questions being posted to ask about *connecting material from different courses* vs. asking about *prerequisites for a course* will be sufficiently different so as to justify making a new tag.

(Incidentally, my sense is that the linked question might be closer to *prerequisites*, but that is perhaps best left for the OP to decide.)

Another possibility is to note that the connections being made are really about connecting material. A casual way to indicate this would be with a tag named, e.g., **making-connections**, with the appropriate tag description. For example, the linked question is, to some extent, about students realizing "that sequences could be seen as functions." A drawback to this tag is its generality: A gentle counter-argument to my own suggestion would be, how often is learning/teaching mathematics *not* about making connections?

A third possibility is to introduce a tag such as **teacher-interactions** since, in my estimation, the key part of the accepted answer involves talking to the other teachers.

---

**An irresistible side-note:** One of the difficulties in wording this tag is that "class" takes on more than one meaning in the context of education, e.g., lower class (typically referred to now as lower socioeconomic status or low SES) as opposed to a class on algebra. The simplest workaround is to use the word "course" instead. This latter approach has at least two drawbacks. First, one of the terms around using/applying knowledge from one area in another area is "transfer"; but "course-transfer" is quite confusing, since it sounds more like credits are being transferred programmatically. Second, the typical prefix to denote between/among is "inter-", e.g., between/among disciplines would be "interdisciplinary" -- this road leads to a very particular issue with the word "course"...